# Multiple checkboxes not being set in AG Grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ag-grid

I have checkboxes on my rows and I am trying to select more than one. When I click one it checks fine. If I click a checkbox on another row that checkbox selects but the one I was on is de-selected.

HTML:

```
<div>
  <ag-grid-angular
    #dataVisGrid
    style="width: 1000px; height: 500px;"
    class="ag-theme-balham"
    [rowData]="rowData"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    [rowSelection]="multiple"
    [rowMultiSelectWithClick]="true"
    [enableRangeSelection]="true"
    (rowClicked)="onRowSelect($event)">

  </ag-grid-angular>
</div>
```

data-vis-component.js

```
columnDefs = [
  {headerName: 'Data Source', field: 'dataSource', sortable: true, filter: true, checkboxSelection: true},
  {headerName: 'Value', field: 'value', sortable: true, filter: true},
  {headerName: 'State', field" 'state', sortable: true, filter: true}
];

onRowSelect(event) {
  console.log("onRowSelect:"+JSON.stringify(event));
}
```

If I ctrl-click on the row I can see multiple rows highlight (because of `enableRangeSelection`). However, only one checkbox works.

Based on the documentation this appears to be the way you set this up - but for some reason its not working for me. Anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set row selection to a variable and set the variable to "multiple"

```
[rowSelection]="rowSelection"
```

and  inside the component

```
this.rowSelection = "multiple";
```

Or you can remove the [ ] wrapped around rowselection

```
rowSelection="multiple"
```

as  multiple is a string and not a variable

Comment: That was it... the setting of multiple inside the component. Thanks!